# Angularjs Autocomplete typehead with json data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, json

I have used angularjs typehead for autocomplete function after defining the controller and ng-app in my html page.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="selected" uib-typeahead="location for location getLocation($viewValue)" typeahead-loading="loadingLocations" typeahead-no-results="noResults" class="form-control" placeholder="json data">
<i ng-show="loadingLocations" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></i>
<div ng-show="noResults">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> No Results Found
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$scope.getLocation = val => {

    return $http.get('./resultlocation.json', {
        params: {
            address: val
        }
    }).then(response => {
        return response(item => item.name);
    });

};
```

Comment: in html it is <input type="text" ng-model="selected" uib-typeahead="location for location in getLocation($viewValue)" typeahead-loading="loadingLocations" typeahead-no-results="noResults" class="form-control" placeholder="json data ">

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: There is no question. Please, provide one.

Comment: data is not coming in autocomplete its everytime showing no result found